# imagemagick tiled / toroidal offset

Tags: imagemagick

I'm looking for the most efficient way to offset the content of an image as if it was a torus surface. In other words, I want the parts that move outside the canvas to come back on the other side (e.g. left to right and up to down).

Is there a dedicated argument for that?

Comment: I think you mean `-roll` but it's hard to tell... https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#roll

Comment: -roll is the correct method in ImageMagick as Mark Setchell has indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark Setchell has pointed out, -roll +X+Y is the correct method in ImageMagick. In the following, I roll the image to the right by half of its width.

Input:

[image]

```
convert mandril3.jpg -roll +128+0 mandril3_roll.jpg
```

Result:

[image]